# Remove first tag html using python & scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have a HTML:

```
<div class="abc">
            <div class="xyz">
                <div class="needremove"></div>
                <p>text</p>
                <p>text</p>
                <p>text</p>
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I used: 
    response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"abc")]/div[contains(@class,"xyz")]').extract()

Result:

```
u'['<div class="xyz">
        <div class="needremove"></div>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>']
```

I want remove `<div class="needremove"></div>`. May you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the child tags except the `div` with `class="needremove"`:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "abc")]/div[contains(@class, "xyz")]/*[local-name() != "div" and not(contains(@class, "needremove"))]').extract()
```

Demo from the shell:

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
In [1]: response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "abc")]/div[contains(@class, "xyz")]/*[local-name() != "div" and not(contains(@class, "needremove"))]').extract()
Out[1]: [u'<p>text</p>', u'<p>text</p>', u'<p>text</p>', u'<p>text</p>']
```

Comment: But i don't want get `p` text. I want get all html tag and remove `<div class="needremove"></div>`

Comment: @mydo47 ok, I've updated the answer. Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: thank you so much. But if i want result: `u'['<div class="xyz">
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>']`. Have you a different way?

Comment: @mydo47 good. Can you explain the motivation behind this requirement? What are you going to do next with the HTML block you are trying to extract? Thanks.

Comment: I 'll save it to my database and show my website. Your answer is awesome. Solved my issue. But i find a different way. Just learn python & scrapy more.